# How can i group dates in months (Jan, Feb, March, etc.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i got 1 table like this

```
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| name  | date       | quantity | price   |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art1  | 2017-01-05 | 10       | 5543.32 |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art2  | 2017-01-15 | 16       | 12.56   |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art3  | 2017-02-08 | 5        | 853.65  |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art4  | 2017-03-06 | 32       | 98.65   |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
```

And i want to show this information

```
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| name  | January    | February | March   |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art1  | 5543.32    | 0        | 0       |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art2  | 12.56      | 0        | 0       |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art3  | 0          | 853.65   | 0       |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
| art4  | 0          | 0        | 98.65   |
+-------+------------+----------+---------+
```

How can i do that? I'm a bit rusty in sql.
Thanks

Comment: You need to group by month (search the hundreds of questions already asked on that) and then pivot it (search the hundreds of questions already asked on that)

Comment: What does this have to do with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation:

```
select name,
       sum(case when date >= '2017-01-01' and date < '2017-02-01' then price else 0 end) as january,
       sum(case when date >= '2017-02-01' and date < '2017-03-01' then price else 0 end) as february,
       sum(case when date >= '2017-03-01' and date < '2017-04-01' then price else 0 end) as march
from t
group by name;
```

Comment: Not when you run it with the sample data you provided it doesn't. It returns exactly your desired output.

Comment: yes you're right, it was showing 0's because my the date format of my DBMS, is dd/mm/aaaa, just change '2017-01-01' to '01/01/2017', and it works!!!.
Thanks